# Как процессу bat файла дать название?

Tags: cmd, bat

Есть такой код в одном bat файле

```
set ProcessName=KPrimeru.bat
tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME eq %ProcessName%" | find /i "%ProcessName%"
if errorlevel 1 ( 
echo 123
) else ( 
taskkill /F /im %ProcessName%
)
```

Но дело в том, что мне нужно сделать проверку для процесса, которым в последствии является другой bat файл, каким образом я могу задать ему название в процессах, чтобы далее использовать его для команды выше?

```
title KPrimeru.bat
```

Не помогает. А делать проверку на просто cmd - бессмысленно. Я знаю о способах превратить bat файл в exe, либо же применить сюда vbs, но через команды bat возможно выполнить мою задачу?

Comment: Bat2exe тоже не является выходом, потому что те, что я видел предварительно сохраняли bat на диск и запускали его.

Comment: Скорее всего, потребуется поиск по маске **/fi  "windowtitle eq KPrimeru.bat*"**.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте способность интерпретатора командной строки к изменению заголовка окна.

В коде вызываемого батника, который надо будет "прибить", задайте нужный заголовок.

```
title abyrvalg
```

В коде контролирующего батника ищите нужный процесс по заголовку:

```
tasklist /fi "windowtitle eq abyrvalg"
```

Может не сработать фильтр поиска, посчитав что есть дополнительные символы в заголовке окна. Поэтому используйте маску. Например, так:

```
taskkill /fi "windowtitle eq KPrimeru.bat*"
```